# Unable to Install mysql workbench on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using Ubuntu LTS 15.10. I am unable to install mysql workbench.

I have tried all version of mysql-version but still getting this issue:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to google the library? This is a simple dependency issue...

Comment: Have you tried this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/420054/trouble-installing-mysql-workbench

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?